# Trigger function just before exit

Tags: php, debian, dhtmlx-scheduler

I'm using [DHTMLX Scheduler](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/) on the front end and DHTMLX Connector on the backend as part of my radio automation app.  Every time a user edits the calendar, an AJAX call is made to a file that looks like this:

```
require_once("dhtmlxScheduler_v4/connector/scheduler_connector.php");
require_once('QDRAconf.php');

$res = mysql_connect($QDRAconf['mysqlHost'], $QDRAconf['mysqlUser'], $QDRAconf['mysqlPass']);
mysql_select_db($QDRAconf['mysqlDb']);

// init the schedulerconnector
$conn = new SchedulerConnector($res);

// render the table
$conn->render_table("events","id","start_date,end_date,text");
```

This file is my "shim" that hooks up the fronted to the back end.  I want to run another PHP script that writes the changes to my crontab, but it needs to happen *after* the DHTMLX library has updated the database.  Trouble is, the DHTMLX library will automatically exit whenever it thinks it's done: sometimes it might not get past the first `require_once('...')` line so I can't just put `require_once('cronwriter.php');` at the last line of the script.

My solution to this was to create a class with a destructor that updates the crontab with the latest changes.  Since the php manual [states that](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) destructors will still be run if the exit() or die() function is called, I added a dummy class with a destructor that runs `cronwriter.php` script:  (I added this to the beginning of the file.)

```
class ExitCatcher
{
    function __destruct()
    {
        require_once('cronwriter.php');
    }
}
//init the class
$ExitCatcher = new ExitCatcher;
```

For some reason, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) may offer a quick solution; but, you might save yourself some future trouble by inspecting the cause of that library's sporadic process haltings.

A good place to start might be...

- your browser's JS [console](http://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) for JS errors
- your JS console's network tab for AJAX errors
- your server's error logs for PHP errors